# Shortcut for zooming in OpenOffice.org

Tags: openoffice

Is there a shortcut for zooming in OpenOffice.org?

I'm using OpenOffice version 3.2.1 and a quick look at the documentation didn't reveal anything.

Comment: The corresponding menu command is: menu View/Zoom. Or double click on the lower right (the % field in the status bar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to zoom in or out in the *Normal View* you can use CTRL and the scroll wheel from your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=27118&highlight=keyboard+font+increase+size) thread.  To sum it up, you'll have to manually create the keyboard shortcuts.  (By the way, I'm working on the assumption that you're wanting to make fonts bigger or smaller, not actually zoom the view in or out.)

Comment: painful; doesn't even work for me; thanks for the link

Comment: Sorry to hear that!